# How extend the root application with Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How extend the root application with Nuxtjs as in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBhia7uBxDA) , This is not working now, Is there anyway to customize the Nuxt.js  App Layout. Thanks for any solutions in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes finally got it, Using plugin and mixins

```
export default function({ app }) {
  if (!app.mixins) {
    app.mixins = []
  }
  app.mixins.push({
    mounted() {
    //..  do here
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: where were that app object coming from?